# Django allauth example [Errno 111] - Connection refused

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have the following error when login by FB in Django app which was uploaded to heroku:

```
ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/facebook/login/token/
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Did I miss somethings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your login requires sending or authenticating Email before allowing you to login, then maybe you wouldn't have set up the EMAIL_BACKEND to 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' in your settings.py file, of course along with the other necessary things, if you have a gmail account:

```
SERVER_EMAIL = '************@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '**********@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**********'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '****'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '*********@gmail.com'
```

I think this would solve your problem if ConnectionRefused was your error.